# Attempt to read property "id" on bool. But only in edit form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-9

I would like to add a `dropdown` and `input` in edit form with options from a table (class), so I am using `foreach`. It works fine when I only have the input form, but it gives an error when I add the edit form. I don't understand why. Please help, I'm new to Laravel.

Here's my
[input form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVLis.png)
(I want to make an edit form like this too, with same inputs and dropdown)

Here's my code.

**Views**

```
    <!-- INPUT FORM (MODAL) -->
<form method="post" action="{{ url('/grade/create') }}">
    @csrf
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-8 mb-3">
            <label>SNum</label>
            <input type="text" pattern="M+[0-9]{7,}" minlength="8" maxlength="8" class="form-control" name="SNum"
                required="required" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label>Class</label>
            <select class="form-select" name="class[]">
                {{-- Works fine --}}
                @foreach ($class as $class)
                    <option value="{{ $class->id }}">{{ $class->class }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

@foreach ($grades as $grade)
    <!-- EDIT FORM (MODAL) -->
    <form method="post" action="{{ url('/grade/update' . $grade->id) }}">
        @csrf
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-8 mb-3">
                <label>SNum</label>
                <input type="text" value="{{ $grade->SNum }}" pattern="M+[0-9]{7,}" minlength="8"
                    maxlength="8" class="form-control" name="SNum" required="required" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4 mb-3">
                <label>Class</label>
                <select class="form-select" name="class[]" id="class{{ $grade->id }}">
                    @foreach ($class as $class)
                        {{-- Attempt to read property "id" on bool --}}
                        <option value="{{ $class->id }}">{{ $class->class }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal{{ $grade->id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <form method="post" action="{{ url('/grade/delete/' . $grade->id) }}">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="modal-body"
                        style="height:100px; display:flex; align-items:center; justify-content:center;">
                        <h5 class="text-center">Are you sure?</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Ya</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

**Controller**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Grade;
use App\Models\GradeClass;
use App\Models\Class;

class MainController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $grades = Grade::get();
        $class = Class::get();
        return view('main', compact('grades', 'class'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'SNum' => 'required|max:8|min:8',
            'class' => 'required'
        ]);

        $grade = Grade::create([
            'SNum' => $request['SNum']
        ]);

        if ($request->has('class')) {
            foreach ($request['class'] as $classId) {
                GradeClass::create([
                    'grades_id' => $grade->id,
                    'class_id' => (int) $classId,
                ]);
            }
        }

        return redirect('/')->with('status', 'Grade added!');
    }

    public function update(Request $request, Grade $grade)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'SNum' => 'required|max:8|min:8',
            'class' => 'required'
        ]);

        $grade->SNum = $request['SNum'];
        $grade->save();

        GradeClass::where('grades_id', $grade->id)->delete();

        if ($request->has('class')) {
            foreach ($request['class'] as $classId) {
                GradeClass::create([
                    'grades_id' => $grade->id,
                    'class_id' => (int) $classId,
                ]);
            }
        }
        return redirect('/')->with('status', 'Grade updated!');
    }
    public function destroy(Grade $grade)
    {
        GradeClass::where('grades_id', $grade->id)->delete();
        $grade->delete();

        return redirect('/')->with('status', 'Grade deleted!');
    }
}
```

**Route**

```html
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\MainController;

Route::get('/', [MainController::class, 'index']);
Route::controller(MainController::class)->prefix('grade')->name('grade.')->group(function () {
    Route::post('/create', 'store')->name('store');
    Route::post('/update/{grade}', 'update')->name('update');
    Route::post('/delete/{grade}', 'destroy')->name('destroy');
});
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing this:

```
@foreach ($class as $class)
```

Even though this works, one time at least, you have destroyed the original $class variable at the end of the loop, so it is no longer the array of objects you started with.

Fix your code so that the result array is passed to blade as a variable named $classes, so that you can use:

```
@foreach ($classes as $class)
```